# Invalid implicit conversion from address to contract

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging

Im trying to import a contract and call its primary function via another contract. This seems to work in most cases but in this case i get the following error.

**localhost/tokenmarket/SecurityToken.sol:8:25: TypeError: Invalid type for argument in modifier invocation. Invalid implicit conversion from address to contract UpgradeableToken requested.
    TestMigrationTarget(_oldToken) {**
                        ^-------^

1. Code of the contract im getting this issue with.

   ```
   pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
   import "./test/TestMigrationTarget.sol";

   contract UpgraderToken is TestMigrationTarget {
    function UpgraderToken(address _oldToken)
       TestMigrationTarget(_oldToken) {
   }
   }
   ```
2. Code of Contract TestMigrationTarget which it is importing which deploys fine on its own.

   ```
   pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

   import "../SafeMathLib.sol";
   import "../UpgradeableToken.sol";
   import "../MintableToken.sol";


   contract TestMigrationTarget is StandardTokenExt, UpgradeAgent {

     using SafeMathLib for uint;

     UpgradeableToken public oldToken;

     uint public originalSupply;

     function TestMigrationTarget(UpgradeableToken _oldToken) {

       oldToken = _oldToken;

       // Let's not set bad old token
       if(address(oldToken) == 0) {
         throw;
       }

       // Let's make sure we have something to migrate
       originalSupply = _oldToken.totalSupply();
       if(originalSupply == 0) {
         throw;
       }
     }

     function upgradeFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public {
       if (msg.sender != address(oldToken)) throw; // only upgrade from oldToken

       // Mint new tokens to the migrator
       totalSupply_ = totalSupply_.plus(_value);
       balances[_from] = balances[_from].plus(_value);
       Transfer(0, _from, _value);
     }

     function() public payable {
       throw;
     }

   }
   ```
3. Another case where import and calling functions works just fine.

   ```
   pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

   import "./BurnableCrowdsaleToken.sol";

   contract MyToken is BurnableCrowdsaleToken {
       function MyToken(string _name, string _symbol, uint _initialSupply, uint _decimals, bool _mintable)
       CrowdsaleToken(_name, _symbol, _initialSupply, _decimals, _mintable) {
     }
   }
   ```

What am i doing wrong in step 1 and how can it be addressed ?

Thanks for reading and your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is exactly what the error message says. You are trying to implicitly convert between `UpgradeableToken` and `address` - your lower level contract passes on the parameter of type `address` but upper level contract expects type `UpgradeableToken`.

Change the contract `UpgradeableToken` to access an `address` parameter and it should be fine. You can then cast the `address` into a `UpgradeableToken` like this: `UpgradeableToken tok = UpgradeableToken(_oldToken);`.

P.S. What you are referring to as "primary function" is actually called a constructor. You should also use a newer version of Solidity and get used to using the `constructor` keyword instead of special function name - your way will no longer work starting from Solidity 0.5.

Comment: Thanks Lauri, i was able to however use this workaround without needing to change the UpgradeableToken contract by doing this instead

function UpgraderToken(UpgradeableToken _oldToken) TestMigrationTarget(_oldToken) public {
  }

Thanks for sharing info on solidity 0.5 mandating constructor() instead of function with same name as contract. good to know for future. cheers.